# Matrix amplification of a $C^*$-algebras

Tags: tensor-products, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

This is probably a very basic question. When discussing the $n-$fold amplification of a $C^*$-algebra, $M_n(A)$, we frequently denote it by the tensor product $A\otimes M_n(\mathbb{C})$. Why do we have this identification?

Does this follow from the distributive properties of tensor products (of modules over commutative rings)? And, if so, how?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is checked directly. Define $\gamma:M_n(A)\to A\otimes M_n(\mathbb C)$ by
$$
\gamma:[A_{kj}]\longmapsto \sum_{kj}A_{kj}\otimes E_{kj}.
$$
It is trivial to verify that this is a $*$-isomorphism.

Comment: Maybe you should also say something about the tensor product on the right. There are no topological technicalities because $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ has finite dimension.